# Concatenate Massive Amount of Images with Similar Names

Tags: image, imagemagick, concatenation, graphicsmagick

I have many, many pictures that I try to concatenate together.

They all follow a similar naming convention.

- $Child_HF2_5.png
- $Child_HF2_5_ISO.png
- $Child_HF2_5_POSE.png
- $Child_HF2_6.png
- $Child_HF2_6_ISO.png
- $Child_HF2_6_POSE.png
- $Dwarf_TD_Female_3.png
- $Dwarf_TD_Female_3_ISO.png
- $Dwarf_TD_Female_3_POSE.png

I want to concatenate vertically images with similar names together. They also all have the same size.

Ex:

- $Child_HF2_5.png +
- $Child_HF2_5_ISO.png +
- $Child_HF2_5_POSE.png

to form a new picture named $Child_HF2_5_FULL.png

---

What software would you recommend me to use to do such a thing and how hard would it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that ImageMagick could be a great choice. It shouldn't be too difficult, for example you can try this command:

```
montage $Child_HF2_5*.png -tile 1x3 -geometry +0+0 $Child_HF2_5_FULL.png
```

In this sample command I had 3 images, so I used `-tile 1x3`; if you have n images you'll have to use `-tile 1xn`

input:

[image: $Child_HF2_5.png] [image: $Child_HF2_5_ISO.png] [image: $Child_HF2_5_POSE.png]

output:

[image: $Child_HF2_5_FULL.png]